# Post migration MySQL database validation

Tags: mysql, data, data-validation

We are migrating from 5.5 enterprise mysql to 8.0 mysql enterprise edition. And we are migrating version by version like from 5.5 to 5.6 then 5.6 to 5.7 and lastly from 5.7 to 8.0  also os migration is there from the rhel5. 4 to 8.4 it's all okay but client want data validation value by value. Normal data validations like row counts, and checksum is not sufficient to client as data is senstive.  Suggest any good tool, script or query to check value to value data validation

Comment: "8.4"??  MySQL is still on "8.0.xx".  I hope you did not mean "8.0.4"; that was a "re-release" version.

Comment: 5.5 to 8.0 is a huge leap.  Condolences.  You will probably encounter a lot of "little" things that get in your way.  I recommend you test the conversion outside of production and set aside a non-trivial amount of time.

Comment: "Data validation" is _very_ unlikely to be a problem.  If I recall correctly, 5.6 is when the internal storage format of `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` was changed.  This was automatically handled, but it necessitated a full rewrite of tables with such columns.

Comment: How to deal with this datetime and timestamp change. On puc/uat we done migration from 5.6 to 8.0.2 as mentioned version by version along with os update

Answer (score 0):

I would use [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html).

This is a free tool from Percona. It's a command-line tool, implemented in Perl. You use it by giving arguments describing connections to both the original database instance and the new database instance. It compares row by row (really small groups of rows at a time), and then generates a diff, so that you could make the new instance have the same data as the original.

You can use the tool to execute the change to synchronize the data, or optionally you can make it only report the diff, and do nothing to change data. Read the documentation I linked to for more information.

Comment: is this tool capable enough to validate row by row with 2 TB of data size?

Comment: Yes, it works by iterating over the primary key of the table, comparing small groups of rows. There's no reason it would not work regardless of table size, it will just take time. I have used it on some pretty big tables (hundreds of GB), although I can't claim that I've used it for a 2TB database. Anyway, that is the tool I can recommend.

Comment: Ok but any idea how much time it will take for compare 1 billion rows validation.

Comment: I can't predict that. There are many factors that could affect it. The size per row, the power of your server, any other concurrent load on the server, and so on. You will have to test it yourself on your database on your server. That's the only way to know. You might want to start by specifying one of your smaller tables and then as you get a feel for how long it takes to run on your servers, proceed to the larger tables.

Comment: Ok will test and update

Comment: We are working on python script for compare data. Tool is ignored :(

Comment: Ok then, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

(This addresses the Comment about the format of DATETIME and TIMESTAMP changing.)

There are (based on documentation) two ways that the internal format is changed:

- If you dump (eg, via `mysqldump`) the data (from the old version) and load it on the new server with a newer version, the format change is changed without any hint that it is happening.  This is because of converting from the old internal format to a string, then to the new internal format.
- If you "upgrade in place", then the upgrade process takes the time to rebuild each table that has a datetime or timestamp.  (There may be some option for delaying the format change, but I am not familiar with the details.)

The bottom line is that format change is automatic, though may add time to the upgrade.

The internal structure of an InnoDB tables representation on disk makes it essentially impossible to do anything akin to a byte-by-byte file comparison.  (This statement is valid even when there is no change to an internal data format.)

You can, however, copy all the mysql files from one disk to another, then verify byte-by-byte that the *files* were still intact.  This is a simple way to create a new Replica.  However, once mysqld touches a table, the simple byte comparison is rendered invalid.